# Passing Parsed Data to Callback in Order to Use Freely

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, callback

I want to know if there is anyway to pass the value of coins or, more ideally, currency to my callback function at the end so i can use the parsed JSON data freely in other functions.

```
function loadJSON(path, callback) {
  var json = new XMLHttpRequest();
  json.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (json.readyState == 4) {
      if (json.status == 200) {
          var coins = JSON.parse(json.responseText);
          setTimeout(function(){
          coins.forEach(function(currency){
         //console.log(currency.name + "\x09\x09\x09" + currency.price_usd + " USD");
       }, 5000);
       });
      }
      // else {
      //   error(json);
      // }
    }
  };

  json.open("GET", path, true);
  json.send();
  callback();
}
```

I'm new to JS so any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You forgot to close the `forEach(function() {` with a `});` ...

Comment: See also [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Answer (score 1):

Just move the callback to the position were you got the data:

```
   var coins = JSON.parse(json.responseText);       
   setTimeout(function(){
      callback(coins); 
   }, 5000);
```

If you want to get the same as logged into your console (the currencies), you could map the coins array to a new array containing that format:

```
    callback(coins.map(function(currency) {
       return currency.name + "\x09\x09\x09" + currency.price_usd + " USD";
    }));
```